# Prevent CSS overwrites from web components in parent page

Tags: css, angular, web-component, angular-elements

I created a web component using Angular Elements (6.0.3). When I use the web component in another website, the webcomponent overwrites the styles of the parent page since it also uses Bootstrap. I know that there is the view encapsulation principle, but as far as I know the "Native" encapsulation is [not yet fully supported](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23636). So for now I am using the default "Emulated".

I found out that if I add `:host ::ng-deep` in front of my styles, they are only applied to the web component itself which is great. However, all css and scss files that I load in angular.json seem to be overwriting the parent page too. Is there any way I can prevent this behaviour from imported style-files?

My style-imports in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/css/intlTelInput.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
  "src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "src/assets/css/wizard.css",
  "src/assets/css/calendar.css",
  "src/assets/css/ng2-select.css"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'styles' imports in the angular.json are for styles you wish to define globally to the whole app. To use `ViewEncapsulation` you'll need to link their stylesheets inside of their components like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
```